Electrostatic Potential vs. Field Energy: Understanding the Difference
Could you explain the difference between electrostatic potential energy and the energy of the electromagnetic field in the case of an electrostatic field? For example, if I have two nearby charged particles, the energy of the system is given by $ U = \frac{k q_1 q_2}{r} $, which represents the energy required to assemble the system. On the other hand, the field energy is calculated as $ U_{\text{field}} = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int E^2 \, dV $. Are these two quantities equal? If not, what is the difference between them?
Initially, I thought they were equal, but something doesn’t add up. Considering a single point charge, $ U_{\text{field}} = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int E^2 \, dV $ is non-zero, yet the energy required to assemble the configuration should be zero. How can this discrepancy be resolved?


SimoBartz: How can this discrepancy be resolved?

The discrepancy could be solved exactly by the difference between the electrostatic energy and the energy of the electromagnetic field. The first only contains the energy due to interactions, and the last one contains self energy, i.e., the energy of a charge due to itself.
You could check it by yourself, by explicitly calculating the expression for two charges, or you could check it in [1].
This explains why a single charge has electromagnetic energy stored in its field (self-energy), but no electrostatic potential energy (no interaction).

[1] Classical Electrodynamics second edition. J.D. Jackson. Section 1.11 pg 47.

Short and precise answer. A side question arises for me. Do the fields of electron and proton strip off when they approach each other? Both have two field components (E and B) and the photons emitted when they approach each other also have these field components.

I don't know the answer of your question, but it seems a good one :)

In the gauge theory all interaction energy and momentum is included in the field energy. The essence of gauge theory is that only $\bf E$ and $\bf B$ have physical meaning.
